# angular 2 call initial function before first routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an app where i want to load all the messages from the server before actually loading the app.

I've put the http request in my app component in OnInit.

but I don't have a way to make the routing "wait" before fetching the first page and the application is starting with empty messages.

Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `APP_INITIALIZER` for this:

Add this to the providers array of your `AppModule`:

```
{provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appInitFactory, deps: [MsgLoader], multi: true}
```

Then create a function factory which obtains your messages. This should return an arrow function returning the actual `Promise`:

```
export function appInitFactory(msg: MsgLoader): () => Promise<any> {
    return () => msg.loadMessages();
}
```

If you don't mind that the `AppComponent` loads, but do mind about its subpages being loaded, you can use the `initialNavigation` property on your root routing:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {initialNavigation: false})
```

This prevents loading of the first module. You should however have some service injected into your `AppComponent` which handles the loading of your messages, and then routes to the required module

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

When you define your routes, add a `prehome` page and `PreHomeComponent`:

```
 imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'prehome', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'prehome', component: PreHomeComponent },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: "job/:id", component: JobComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'prehome' }
        ]),
        MaterialModule
    ]
```

in your `PreHomeComponent` load your required messages from the server and then redirect to `home`.