# Executing a function on page visit in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an OIDC project with a couple of ANGULAR 2+ apps connected to it and was wondering how to execute a function when the user visits one of the applications. Something like onInit in AppComponent but i tried that with no luck. Basically i need to run it once everytime the domain has been visited and the user has logged on.

Comment: Why  not use ngOninit() of AppComponent  ?

Comment: tried. doesnt seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Did you check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265243/angular-2-call-initial-function-before-first-routing

Comment: You can make an EventListner each time the User logged in, you will trigger an event to run your function,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `main.ts` file in your `src` directory. I bring here an example from a project in **Angular 10** i'm working on.

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You should try writing your code there, like this:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

awesomeCode()
{
    // code here
}

awesomeCode();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```